# Https redirect url support for box api using appery.io cloud IDE

Tags: url, redirect, https, box-api

I have developed an application using *appery.io cloud* IDE.

This ide supports only http protocol, but ***box*** api requires https protocol for redirect url.

Is there any way for entering http url instead https?

Answer (score 0):

For security purposes, the entire API requires HTTPS.

Comment: O, thanks. I found answer for my problem 
<script>
if(location.protocol == "https:") {
location = location.href.replace('https', 'http');
}
</script>